# Python Pandas: Indexing Instances of a Dataframe Separately within a For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, indexing

I have the following Dataframe:

```
Rec  Channel  Value1  Value2 
Pre             10      20
Pre             35      42
Event    A      23      39
FF              50      75
Post     A      79      11
Post     B      88      69
```

And have got to the point where with the following code:

```
res = df[df['Channel'].isin({'A', 'B'})
```

I am able to find all the instances in the Dataframe where the column 'Channel' has values of either A or B.  I now am trying to determine a way to use a For Loop so that it will go through and print each row where A or B is found separately.

The reasoning for a For Loop is that this is just a sample Dataframe, my application is going to have a dynamic value of A and B's found depending on the Dataframe and I would like to be able to call upon each individually regardless of the number of instances.

Additionally, I would like an easy way to index upon the first and last instance where an A or B is found (again, the location is going to be changing from Dataframe to Dataframe) so I can't just do:

```
res1 = res.loc[4]
```

to identify the first one in this case, I need something that is going to be more robust regardless of the index I can call upon the first and last instance.  Can someone please assist?

Comment: You can select the first and last elements of res with `res.iloc[[0]]` and `res.iloc[[-1]]` respectively (use `[ ]` instead of `[[ ]]`if you just want the series)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: Any idea on how to create the For Loop for x number of instances and print them each out separately? @ALollz

Comment: `for i in range(len(res)): print(res.iloc[[i]])` or use `display()` instead of print if you want it to look pretty. This prints them all out, but if you just want the first 10, you could do `for i in range(10)`

Comment: Great, thank you @ALollz!  My last thing I am trying to do is take a slice of two elements above and below each instance within the for loop, is that possible?  What would the syntax of that look like?

Answer (score 1):

It would go something like this:

```
res = df[df.Channel.isin(['A', 'B'])]
for row in df[df.Channel.isin(['A', 'B'])].iterrows():
    row_index = row[0]
```

Comment: I am getting an error stating:     slic = res.loc[slic-2 : slic + 2]
NameError: name 'slic' is not defined

Comment: Can you please advise @iDrwish

Comment: To get the index of the row, I then use it to do a slice with 2 rows before it and 2 rows after it. I thought you need that.

Comment: A caveat is that this assumes you use integer based indexes not strings, correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: I used string indexes there, how would that change things?

Comment: This is the error that I am receiving: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str.  Can you please address?  Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure about the slicing, for example, how would the slice be for the 1st element? Also, there is no context or info on the str index.

Comment: the logic over everything makes sense for what you have, I just need what the syntax would look like for string based indexes as opposed to integer, can you advise @iDrwish?

Comment: For example, I would want the first slice of 'Value 1' to include '10 35 23 50 79' where at 23 is where an A was detected.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Not much, first of all, the df is filtered where `Channel.isin(['A`, `B`]), so there `NaN` columns will be discarded. Second, the slicing for the first element would be 1 + 4, but for element 3, it would be 3-2: 3+2?

Comment: Right, but I'm saying that I am getting an error stating: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str. How do I resolve this issue within your syntax to account for string indexes as opposed to integers? @iDrwish

Comment: `.loc` is for str based indexes while `.iloc` is for positional indexes (AKA int or ordinal). So if you would like to get a slice, then you can pass it as `df.loc[row_index]` and use a `:` before or after it for further slicing.

Comment: res = df[df.Channel.isin(['A', 'B'])]
for row in df[df.Channel.isin(['A', 'B'])].iterrows():
    row_index = row['Value 1]

Comment: slic = res.loc[row_index-2 : row_index+2]

Comment: That is what I have and it is still giving me the same error?  Can you assist please? @iDrwish